# Accessing JSON results from jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm working on a web application to maintain the administration for a restaurant kind of type. The idea is to make new orders, put order items in that, check finance overviews etc...

I've also got a function to see all the orders in a list, when you select one of them, the order data (such as the name, emailadress, location of the customer) shows up in a another element inside the document.

I'm doing that with this function, every `tr` inside the has been given a custom attribute; the `order_id`. When selecting that, a class is given, called `selectedRow`.

```
function select_order(order) {
    var item = $(order);
    if (!item.hasClass("selectedRow")) {
        if (!selectedOrderInformation.is(":visible")) {
            switchScreen(selectedOrderInformation, financeOverview);
        }
        item.parent().find(".selectedRow").removeClass("selectedRow");
        item.addClass("selectedRow");
        selectedOrderInformation.html("loading......");
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/functions/select-order.php",
            type: "get",
            data: {order_id: item.attr("data-order-index")},
            success: function (data) {
                selectedOrderInformation.html(data);
                $("#delete-order-btn").prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("DEBUG: Row is already selected");
    }
}
```

The usage of that function is by doing this:

```
$("#list tbody tr").click(function () {
    select_order(this);
});
```

At the first place, i was deploying all the HTML data via PHP. This took a pretty long time, it could take from 500ms to about 1 second. In my opinion thats pretty long.

I was doing that like this (select-order.php):

```
if (!empty($_GET['order_id'])) {
    $order_id = $_GET['order_id'];

    $order_data = Database::getInstance()->get_all_data_by_order_id($order_id);
    $order_items = Database::getInstance()->get_order_items_by_order_id($order_id);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($order_data)) {
        echo "<h1>Klant informatie</h1>";
        echo "<p>Voornaam: " . $row['first_name'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Achternaam: " . $row['last_name'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Emailadres: " . $row['email_adress'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Klant informatie: " . $row['customer_info'] . "</p>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<h1>Bestellingsinformatie</h1>";
        echo "<p>Order informatie: " . $row['order_info'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Locatie: " . $row['location'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Gemaakt op: " . $row['created'] . "</p>";
    }

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Product naam</th>";
    echo "<th>Hoeveelheid</th>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($order_items)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    exit;
}
```

This goes together with the Database class with all the functions:

```
class Database extends mysqli
{

    // single instance of self shared among all instances
    private static $instance = null;

    private $databaseHost = "";
    private $databaseUser = "";
    private $databasePassword = "";
    private $databaseName = "";

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        trigger_error('Deserializing is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($this->databaseHost, $this->databaseUser, $this->databasePassword, $this->databaseName);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        parent::set_charset('utf-8');
    }


    function get_all_data_by_order_id($order_id) {
        $query = "SELECT customers.first_name,
                         customers.last_name,
                         customers.email_adress,
                         customers.customer_info,

                         orders.order_info,
                         orders.total_price,
                         orders.location,
                         orders.created

                         FROM customers
                 INNER JOIN orders ON customers.id = orders.customer_id

                 WHERE orders.id = {$order_id}";

        return $this->query($query);
    }

    function get_order_items_by_order_id($order_id) {
        $query = "SELECT `products`.`name`, `orders-items`.`quantity` FROM `orders-items`\n" . "INNER JOIN `products`ON `orders-items`.`products_id` = `products`.`id`\n" . "WHERE order_id=" . $order_id;

        return $this->query($query);
    }
}
```

Now someone told me i could better translate the data into json and return that, so i did this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['order_id'])) {
    $order_id = $_GET['order_id'];

    $order_data = Database::getInstance()->get_all_data_by_order_id($order_id);
    $order_items = Database::getInstance()->get_order_items_by_order_id($order_id);

    $rows = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($order_data)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return json_encode($rows);
    exit;
}
```

But as expected, nothing really happened. So i tried changing the javascript to this (trying it as a array because i'm returning it that way?), to deploy one piece of data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/functions/select-order.php",
    type: "get",
    data: {order_id: item.attr("data-order-index")},
    success: function (data) {
        selectedOrderInformation.html(data['first_name']);
    }
});
```

But that didn't work aswell.

**Problems**

- The previous PHP code was to slow, so i had to find another way.
- When trying to deploy HTML into the other screen, it doesnt do anything. It stays on the 'loading...' screen, so the `success` function was'nt reached.

**Question**

How can my piece of code be changed so it will actually deploy parts of the data from the mysql database?

Comment: So to sum up, your ajax request doesn't work ? You have take a look at  the developer tools ?

Comment: @Debflav indeed, but nothing is being logged.

Comment: In the network tab, you're requested page does not return a code 500 ?

Comment: @Debflav Its just saying: 200 OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$.ajax()` call you should define what type your response data is expected to be, by adding the following parameter to the call:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Also, you should try `echo json_encode($rows);` your data instead of `return`ing it.

****Edit**: you are receiving an array of arrays, so your original referencing in the `success` callback won't suffice. Having another look at your MySQL part, If you are only expecting one row to be returned by your query, then you can change your PHP to:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($order_data);
echo json_encode($row); // instead of $rows
```

instead of the `while` loop. That way your `selectedOrderInformation.html(data['first_name']);` will most likely work.

To clean your query up a bit:

```
$query = "SELECT p.name, ot.quantity FROM orders-items AS ot
    LEFT JOIN products AS p ON ot.products_id = p.id
    WHERE ot.order_id = " . $order_id;
```

You could also switch your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` in your "get order data" function. An inner join is absolutely useless here, as you'll have all your data paired based on the foreign keys anyways.

I would try secluding some of the codebase: try commenting out the `Database::getInstance()` calls, and supplementing some testdata into the processes. To put it short, fake a returned response, by declaring a `$row = array('first_name' => 'Joe', 'order_date' => '2014-08-29 11:11:52', ...);` and returning that. If its way faster, then your database server might be the bottleneck. If its still slow, then 500ms - 1000ms is actually argueably code related, it might be other hardware aspects that cause the problem. Or for example, do you have your jQuery library loaded from a CDN, or locally?

****Edit**: As @Debflav pointed out (and I've also touched upon the matter), that your queries could benefit from not being executed as simple queries, but transforming them into prepared statements. For the full story you could start checking out [PHP.net : Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or to keep it short:

Prepared statements look almost just like your everyday query, however variables are not just concatenated into the query string, rather bindings are used.
You use the database handler's `prepare` function instead of `query` - with this method, you are requesting the MySQL server to inspect your query and optimize it for later use (which will come handy if you're doing the same query over and over again, just with a few varying values).

For more detailed insights on the mechanics of prepared statements and how to get the hang of it for efficiently utilizing it in your projects I recommend you research the topic a bit, but as a quick conversion for your example at hand, it would look like this:

```
function get_all_data_by_order_id($order_id) {
    $query = "SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, c.email_adress, c.customer_info, 
                  o.order_info, o.total_price, o.location, o.created
                  FROM customers AS c
                  LEFT JOIN orders AS o ON c.id = o.customer_id
                  WHERE o.id = :order_id";
    $query_params = array( 
        ':order_id' => $order_id 
    ); 

    $preparedStatement = $this->prepare($query);
    return $preparedStatement->execute($query_params);

}
```

and

```
function get_order_items_by_order_id($order_id) {
    $query = "SELECT p.name, ot.quantity FROM orders-items AS ot
                  LEFT JOIN products AS p ON ot.products_id = p.id
                   WHERE ot.order_id = :order_id;";
    $query_params = array( 
        ':order_id' => $order_id 
    ); 

    $preparedStatement = $this->prepare($query);
    return $preparedStatement->execute($query_params);
}
```

And to reflect on how you would build up your JSON response with data including the order headers and the connected order-items would be:

```
if (!empty($_GET['order_id'])) {
    $order_id = $_GET['order_id'];

    $order_data = Database::getInstance()->get_all_data_by_order_id($order_id);
    $order_items = Database::getInstance()->get_order_items_by_order_id($order_id);

    $orderObject = array();
    $orderObject['header'] = mysqli_fetch_array($order_data);
    $orderObject['items'] = array();    
    while ($orderedItem = mysqli_fetch_array($order_items)){
        $orderObject['items'][] = $orderedItem;
    }

    echo json_encode($orderObject);
}
```

This way your jQuery could look something as follows:

```
....
success: function (data) {
    selectedOrderInformation.html('<h3>' + data['header']['first_name'] + '</h3><ul>');
    $.each(data['items'], function(i, item) {
        selectedOrderInformation.append('<li>' + item['name'] + ' x ' + item['quantity'] + '</li>');
    });
    selectedOrderInformation.append('</ul>');
}
....
```

Comment: I did this and without the `dataType: json` all the data was printed on the document, but it didnt look good and my css for that element went over its height and width limit. When i added the datatype: json, the screen loaded. but there was nothing on it.

Comment: @Bas, I've updated the code - I think you weren't receiving any content as you were referencing the returned result incorrectly (as it was an array with further arrays, and not just an array with keys).

Comment: this worked, but its still pretty slow, how does this come then?

Comment: Well, just a few general notes: the mysqli library already supports prepared statements, so you could take advantage of those, other than that, your query for returning items associated with orders could also be cleaned up a bit. I'll update my answer in a minute (it would be rather ugly to paste in here).

Comment: sorry i g2g right now, off to work. But i'll ready the answer as soon as i come back.

Comment: The new question of OP about _"Why it's still slow ?"_ is too broad. If your queries are fine, the problem can come from your server, your php code 'quality' [...]. Moreover if you are trying to help him with his query please think to **use prepared statements**. +1 for your efforts.

Comment: @Gabor Sorry i had to go and my reactions were so short, had a bit lack of time. But indeed, thanks for your time and explaination, the only thing where i'm worrying about is that the orders-items isnt just a single array, there could be more then just one item in someone's order, so in javascript, how would i do that? because i cant call the `mysqli_fetch_array` there?

Comment: @Gabor Because i now only think i can use it like this: `$('.someElement').html(data['first_name'] + data['last_name']);`

Comment: @Bas : Maybe you should open a new question because Gabor has solved this one.

Comment: @Debflav Yeah okay, you're right. I thought i could just ask further about this question :)

Comment: @Debflav: I've brushed up the answer to include an example of implementing the queries with prepared statements as per our comments.
Bas: I've also included your latest comments solution, however in the future if your original question has been answered, indeed it's best if you start a new question, as to keep questions and their answers more focused on easily overseeable topics.

Comment: @Debflav Ah thanks man! +1 for that. But with the prepared statements, how you remade the functions. The `mysqli_fetch_array` function i'm calling in `select-order.php` is giving me the error message: `Expected mysqli_result, got bool`. Is that because we're not using `$this->query($query);` anymore?

Comment: Well, I'm mostly used to PDO, however I think with mysqli if you are using prepared statements and wish to perform any actions on it after another prepared statement has been run, you'll first have to tell the system to store its results (otherwise it will automatically discard it). This could be achieved with adding `Database::store_result($order_data);` right after your `$order_data = Database::getInstance()->....` row.